# Как правильно спроектироват api?

Tags: ajax, веб-программирование, api, backend

Есть модель некого устройства, к которому через ForeignKey цепляется модель индикаторов. Т. е одно устройство может иметь бесконечное количество индикаторов.
Написал апи, которое по api/device/device_id отдает мне показатели за все время конкретного устройства. На фронте через ajax я забираю их и отрисовываю. Пока тестирую все норм, но беспокоюсь что будут проблемы в дальнейшем. За день таких индикаторов будет капать около 1к, а устройств будет около 50. 
Нужно ли как то отдавать апи по конкретному времени типа api/device/device_id/today, чтобы клиент не мучался от долгой загрузки? Ведь со временем количество индикаторов будет сильно расти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если объём получаемых данных потенциально очень большой, надо сразу предусмотреть порционную отдачу данных.

Чаще всего API реализуют постраничную отдачу, в этом случае заведите необязательный параметр `page`, который будет возвращать данные, например, в виде

```js
{
    page: 1,
    pageCount: 30,
    items: [
        . . .
    ]
}
```

Можно размер страницы устанавливать с клиента, но это добавляет проверок на стороне бекенда. Если нет специальных соображений, размер страницы лучше фиксировать на сервере.

Такой способ хорош для веб-клиентов, но не очень подходит для мобильных, где подгрузка осуществляется при скользящем жесте вверх.

Здесь вместо номера страницы можно использовать необязательный параметр `lastId` или `lastTime`, в котором надо передавать последний полученный с сервера идентификатор или последнее полученное время.

В обоих случаях (и для номера страницы и для последнего полученного идентификатора) отсутствие параметра означает получение начальной (первой) порции данных.

Таким образом, URI сервиса будет выглядеть как **api/device/{device-id}?page=3** или **api/device/{device-id}?lastId=314**.

URI вида **api/device/{device-id}/today** не очень соответствует правилам оформления REST URI, потому что **today** это не подресурс и не поле. Скорее правильно было бы написать **?date=today** и **?date=2019-08-07**.

Кроме того, количество записей, возвращаемых даже для одного дня может всё равно оказаться слишком большим. Так что я бы лично остановился на постраничном списке, если у вас нет каких-то особых требований предоставлять данные посуточно.